# Migrating data from one database to another using LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

Let me start by saying I am relatively new to MySQL. I am trying to migrate data from one database to another. Let us call one database DB1 and the other DB2.

**DB2** has tables the following tables.

**Patient:** `id, person_id and start_regimen_id`

**Regimen:** `id, code`

**Visit:** `id, patient_id, regimen_id,next_appointment_date`

**DB1** has the following tables:

**Patient:** `id,medical_record_number,current_regimen, start_regimen nextappointment`

Now:

**regimen_id** data should be inserted to **current_regimen**

**start_regimen_id** data should be inserted to **start_regimen**

**next_appointment_date** should be inserted to **nextappointment**

This is what I have now:

```
                 SELECT
                    p.person_id AS medical_record_number,
                    r.code AS start_regimen,
                    ??? AS current_regimen,
                    DATE_FORMAT(v.next_appointment_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS 
                    nextappointment,
                FROM patient p
                LEFT JOIN regimen r ON r.id = p.start_regimen_id
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT patient_id, MAX(next_appointment_date) as next_appointment_date 
                    FROM visit 
                    WHERE next_appointment_date IS NOT NULL 
                    GROUP BY patient_id
                ) v ON v.patient_id = p.id
```

I have remained to migrate regimen_id (visit) on DB2 to current_regimen (patient) on DB1. I don't know how to use two LEFT JOIN to get data from two tables for one table.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated because I am really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like we would want to include `regimen_id` in the `GROUP BY` from the `visit` table, and then match that to `id` from the `regimen` table.  Given the outer join, it appears that `patient` may not have any `regimen` associated, so I would include matching of `NULL` values of `regimen_id`.

```
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT vv.patient_id
                , vv.regimen_id
                , MAX(vv.next_appointment_date) AS next_appointment_date 
             FROM visit vv
            WHERE vv.next_appointment_date IS NOT NULL 
            GROUP
               BY vv.patient_id
                , vv.regimen_id
         ) v
      ON v.patient_id = p.id
     AND v.regimen_id <=> r.id
```

But that's just a guess. Without a specification (preferably illustrated by example data and and expected output) we're just guessing.

Note:

```
foo <=> bar
```

is a NULL-safe comparison, a shorthand equivalent to

```
( foo = bar OR ( foo IS NULL AND bar IS NULL ) )
```

Comment: Thanks. It now makes sense. However, what about this part?                      
     ` r.code AS start_regimen
       ??? AS current_regimen`   Since I have already referred to the 'code' column in regimen for start regimen, what about for current_regimen? Will I still use r.code?

Comment: Regimen id is something like 1 and regimen code is something like AF1A